# About files (.vsdx) created by Microsoft visio

Tags: vba, visio

I'm investigating how to automatically update a visio file created with one mastershape (v1.0.vssx) to the next version of the mastershape (v1.1.vssx). When updating each master shape, use Master.Name as the key.

With the code below, I was able to open the vsdx file and vssx and open their respective Masters.

vssx_Master = vssxMaster
vsdx_shape.master = vssx_Master

I wondered if I could update the master shape with the code, but unfortunately vssxMaster is the same as vssxMaster.Name and its type is String.
Is there a way to replace the Master of one shape with another?

not work...

```
Sub Visio_Update(ByRef VISIOpath As String, ByRef except_sheets() As String, ByRef VSSXpath As String)
        
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim vsoApp As Visio.Application
    Dim vsoDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
    Dim vsoItemsCnt As Long
    Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileText As String
           
    FileName = Dir(VISIOpath)
    FileName = Replace(FileName, ".vsdx", "")
    
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.path
    
    Set vsoApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VISIOpath, visOpenRW)
    Set vsoDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(1)
    vsoItemsCnt = vsoApp.Documents.Count
    
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VSSXpath, visOpenRW)
    Set vssxDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(vsoItemsCnt + 1)
    Set vssxMasters = vssxDoc.Masters
    
    For Each vsoPage In vsoDoc.Pages
        For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
            If Not (vsoShape.Master Is Nothing) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                
                mastername = vsoShape.Master.Name
                vsoShape.ReplaceShape vssxMasters.Item(vsoShape.Master.Name)
                        
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    Debug.Print ("Masters.Item")
                    Debug.Print "updated succeeded : ", mastername
                    Err.Clear
                Else
                    Debug.Print ("Masters.Item")
                    Debug.Print Err.Description
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                
            
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    vsoDoc.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.path & "\data\" & FileName & "_updated_.vsdx"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub test()
    choosed_path = "C:\Users\11665307\Desktop\data\vs1.vsdx"
    Update_Template = "C:\Users\11665307\Documents\test.vssx"
    
    Call Visio_Update(choosed_path, except_sheets, (Update_Template))

End Sub
```

I wondered if I could update the master shape with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need iterate all masters into stencil :)

```
For Each vsoPage In doc.Pages
    For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
        If Not (vsoShape.Master Is Nothing) Then
            vsoShape.ReplaceShape vssxMasters.Item(vsoShape.Master.Name)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.

The error I reported was the same as the one described in the forum below.


To find out the cause of the error, I tested it with a very simple vsdx & vssx file (one flow, stencile) instead of the actual file.

The Master to update was a very simple vssx with only the colors changed, but it still didn't work with the same error.

The forum says "The new shape must has the same connection ports as the shape to be replaced." But this didn't help in my environment.

I will try to find a solution myself a little more.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/190959/error-with-shapereplaceshape-method.html

Comment: I've come to understand it little by little. It seems that the replaceshape method can be used with Masters registered in a certain vssx file.

In other words, we can change the Master_1 stencil of the A.vssx file from the Master_1 stencil of the A.vssx file.
we cannot change the Master_1 stencile in the A.vssx file to the Master_1 stencile in the B.vsdx file. For that purpose, some ingenuity is required.

Comment: Not really! You can replace in the document xxx.vsdx the entity from stencil A.vssx with the entity from stencil B.vssx

Comment: I got it. I did  Set vsoApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application") twice. Before each open method.  That 's why

Comment: Finally, I was able to execute the replaceshape method.

Comment: However, there is still one issue.
I have set the stencil with "vsoMaster.MatchByName = True".
In this case, even if I replaced the Master_ stencile in A.vsdx file with the Master_ stencile in B.vssx file with the same name, it did not work well due to the influence of MatchByName = True.

On the other hand, if you set the stencil of the A file to MatchByName = False, the replaceshape method will work, but it will be registered as "Master.11" in the Masters of the A file. I do not want this registration.
Is there a way to execute the replaceshape method with "MatchByName = True"?

Comment: The above problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through all the shapes on the page. If the shape was created based on the master from stencil v.1.0, then replace it with the corresponding master v.1.1. using the [ReplaceShape method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.shape.replaceshape)

```
Sub ttt()
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActivePage.Shapes
    If sh.Master.NameU = "Circle" Then sh.ReplaceShape Application.Documents.Item("BLOCK_M.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Diamond")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So thanks! But I got the error message "Invalid Parameter".

    vsoShape.ReplaceShape (vssxMaster)

Comment: What type of variable **vssxMaster** ?